# R: dependency handling in local package installation

Tags: r, install.packages

I am running R on a Linux based cluster which does not have access to the internet.
So i have downloaded the source files of the packages and the source files of their dependencies. Now i am installing the packages using this command:

```
install.packages("/home/R/stringr_1.0.0.tar.gz" , repos = NULL, type="source")
```

This works for the packages without dependencies. 
I am looking for a command which search for the dependency packages locally at the same path of the source which is supposed to be installed by this command .

Thanks

Comment: Set up a local cran mirror in your environment.

Comment: Thanks.   Can you please guide me how to set up a local cran mirror?

Comment: See: https://cran.r-project.org/mirror-howto.html Depending on your environment you can rsync to your home dir and run some light weight web server on a unprivileged port whenever you need it.